# Chaining resource in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise

I would like to chain resource in AngularJS.

The goal is that resource B wait the end of ressource A before the launch.

I tried this:

```
var p = $q.when(true);
p = p.then(function() {
    return $resource(...).query().$promise;
});
p = p.then(function() {
    return $resource(...).query().$promise;
});
p = p.then(function() {
    return $resource(...).query().$promise;
});
```

The point is that the call is not synchronous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to group many asynchronous calls using `$q.all`.  The docs for this are [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q).

`$q.all()` will allow you to send in all your queries and then wait for them all the return before resolving a combined promise.  However, if you want your queries to happen in a specific order, this may not work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is working fine with `$q.all`but are you sure that `query` return a promise. It's not clear in my mind. "It is important to realize that invoking a $resource object method immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on isArray). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data."

Comment: On a second read of the docs, I think you are right to use `$promise`.  I'll change my answer a bit.